# View created using Join Queries taking too much to load

Tags: mysql, join, view, load

I have written a query to create a view which i can use as a flat table in my application, which is having more than **30 inner join conditions** across **25 tables**.
Now the problem is every time i am selecting the view with even 2-3 columns without adding any further condition or clause, it is taking more that **45-50 seconds** to load.

**No of records in the view : around 250**

**No of Columns in view : 45-50**

My.cnf seems okay, i have checked it using mysqltuner perl script.
I have tweaked the relevant parameters in my.cnf , but no significant effect noticed in query response time.

**Engine Type : InnoDB, Foreign key constraints applied.**

**Mysql version : Percona mysql 5.6**

Any Ideas?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: well views of joins sometime does behave the same in MySQL..have you tried changing the view algorithm from default to either Merge or temptable to see if it give some gain?.

Comment: Do the tables have indexes?

Comment: @ypercube, tables are indexed properly.

Comment: Show us the execution plan then. If the tables are properly indexed and the view has only 250 rows, I don't see how a decent server would need 45 seconds. It should be much faster.

Comment: Does `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` take nearly 45 seconds also?

Comment: sorry for delay in reply..but we have dropped off the idea of using views for this tasks..views created with too many joins will always have consistency and integrity issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your view will join all the tables involved in the view definition in order to create the required view.

First, of course, you should check that your tables are **properly indexed** so that the joins are as efficient as possible when creating the view.

However, joining 25 tables with 30 inner joins is a relatively expensive undertaking, resulting in your case with the 45-50 seconds of delay before getting results.

A good general strategy is to break a big slow step into smaller faster steps. I would consider whether it is possible to create 4 or 5 ***temporary tables*** into which you can insert smaller data sets.  Then once the *temporary tables* exist you could join them together to get a final result.

This does require some design effort in creating the *temporary tables* so that the individual tables create the proper subsets of data for each query.

You can create a **Materialized View** which may work for you depending on your requirements.  Rather than explain the details please look at:

http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

1. You must write code to populate the materialized view and to refresh the data as needed.
2. If you must have the most current data, then you will need to write triggers to provide the needed updates.